# Option with text for a drop-down text box in Toloka

Tags: dropdown, toloka

For the drop down text box, is there way we can option with text from the inputs?

Example:
`{ {select_item value=Attraction4 text=Attraction4}}`

Here Attraction is an input string. But when do put the above code, it does not work. How we can give custom inputs to the drop down list?